# Unit conversion validation bidirectional

Tags: jquery

I'm working on unit conversion project where I am converting units like KG => GRAM or KG=>TON etc. I have to set validation such a way that once unit in selected for conversion eg (KG =>GRAM) it shouldn't allow user to convert from (GRAM =>KG).

Here is my code:

```
<select onchange="checkDuplicateUnitConversion(this,0,'to');" class="to-unit0" name="toUnit">
    <option value="1">kilogram</option>
    <option value="2">gram</option>
</select>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function checkDuplicateUnitConversion(element,row,type)
{
       $("select").each(function(index){        
       });

    switch(type)
    {
        case 'from':
           $("select[name='fromUnit']").each(function(index){
               if(this.value===$('.to-unit'+index).val()){
                           alert("Select Valid Units");
                            $('#addMoreUnitConversion').prop('disabled', true);
                 }
                 else{
                      $('#addMoreUnitConversion').prop('disabled', false);
                 }
           });
        break;

        case  'to':
           $("select[name='toUnit']").each(function(index){

               if(this.value===$('.from-unit'+index).val()){
                           alert("Select Valid Units");
                                $('#addMoreUnitConversion').prop('disabled', true);
                 }
                   else{
                      $('#addMoreUnitConversion').prop('disabled', false);
                 }
           });
        break;    
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want to diss-allow what is shown in the image?

Comment: Yes  i want to disalow if he enters vice versa shown in the image

Comment: Ok, then the below should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but the below should serve your needs:

```js
$('.convert').change(function() {
  $('#warn').html('');
  // loop through each pair of from/to elements
  $('.from').each(function(i, e) {
    var from = $(e).val();
    var to = $('.to').eq($('.from').index($(this))).val();
    var curVals = [from, to];
    // store current values from both in an array
    // loop through each pair of elements again to check against the current values
    $('.from').each(function(chki, chke) {
      // check that this is not the same element from above and that both selects have been selected
      if (chke != e && $.inArray('Select one', curVals) === -1) {
        var from = $(chke);
        var to = $('.to').eq($('.from').index($(this)));
        // get reference to the elements we are checking in this itteration
        // if the both of the checked values are in our temporary value array from the first loop, the conversion is either duplicated or reversed and we need to clear the current elements to avoid that
        if ($.inArray(from.val(), curVals) !== -1 && $.inArray(to.val(), curVals) !== -1) {
          $('#warn').html('Duplicate values removed');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#warn').html('');
          }, 3000);
          from.val('Select one');
          to.val('Select one');
        }
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
#warn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="400" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">From</th>
      <th scope="col">To</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="from convert">
          <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
          <option value="1">kilogram</option>
          <option value="2">gram</option>
          <option value="3">ton</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="to convert">
          <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
          <option value="1">kilogram</option>
          <option value="2">gram</option>
          <option value="3">ton</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="from convert">
          <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
          <option value="1">kilogram</option>
          <option value="2">gram</option>
          <option value="3">ton</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="to convert">
          <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
          <option value="1">kilogram</option>
          <option value="2">gram</option>
          <option value="3">ton</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="from convert">
          <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
          <option value="1">kilogram</option>
          <option value="2">gram</option>
          <option value="3">ton</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="to convert">
          <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
          <option value="1">kilogram</option>
          <option value="2">gram</option>
          <option value="3">ton</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="warn"></div>
```